# Make only one point draggable on highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I would like to have a series of data points displayed on my chart but only a specific one that would be "displayed" and draggable. Is this possible ? I'm using Highcharts javascript

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can return false from drag and drop event callback functions to prevent dragging.

```
    series: [{
        dragDrop: {
            draggableY: true
        },
        point: {
            events: {
                drag: function() {
                    if (this.color !== 'red') {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                drop: function() {
                    if (this.color !== 'red') {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        data: [0, 71.5, {
                y: 106.4,
                color: 'red'
            }, ...
        ]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rx1s73va/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.point.events